# Apache Airflow -- Need to always run a process in a dag whether previous process succeeds or not

Tags: airflow

This usually applies to shutting down some machines.

Say I start an AWS EC2/EMR instance to do some work, and I want to shut it down to avoid having it sitting there.

I would normally do

```
start instance -> do my work1 -> do my work 2 -> shut down instance
```

but let's say `do my work 2` fails, and the `shut down instance` will never be triggered. Is there a way to still trigger the `shut down instance` part of dag?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360853/airflow-run-task-regardless-of-upstream-success-fail

Comment: yea i think that solves my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the task's [TriggerRule](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules). It sounds like you want the trigger rule to be `all_done` so that your last task will execute, regardless of the parent succeeding or failing.