# Run Task on Success or Fail but not on Skipped

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to run a task if the upstream task succeeded or failed but not if the upstream was skipped?

I am familiar with `trigger_rule` with the `all_done` parameter, [as mentioned in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360853/airflow-run-task-regardless-of-upstream-success-fail), but that triggers the task when the upstream has been skipped.  I only want the task to fire on the success or failure of the upstream task.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a trigger rule for success and failed. What you could do is set up duplicate tasks, one with the trigger rule `all_success` and one with the trigger rule `all_failed`. That way, the duplicate task is only triggered if the parents ahead of it fails / succeeds.

I have included code below for you to test for expected results easily.

So, say you have three tasks.

- task1 is your success / fail
- task2 is your success only task
- task3 is your failure only

  ```
  #dags/latest_only_with_trigger.py
  import datetime as dt

  from airflow.models import DAG
  from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
  from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule


  dag = DAG(
  dag_id='stackoverflowtest',
  schedule_interval=dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
  start_date=dt.datetime(2019, 2, 20)
  )

  task1 = DummyOperator(task_id='task1', dag=dag)
  task2 = DummyOperator(task_id='task2', dag=dag,
                        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.all_success)
  task3 = DummyOperator(task_id='task3', dag=dag
                        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.all_failed)

  ###### ORCHESTRATION ###
  task2.set_upstream(task1)
  task3.set_upstream(task1)
  ```

Hope this helps!