# Airflow error handling task trigger rule for triggering directly linked task failure

Tags: airflow

I have an airflow task pipeline as in the diagram. `task1_error_handler` & `task2_error_handler` are error handling tasks which should be ran only if task directly linked is failed. I have set ONE_FAILED trigger rule for these tasks. But seems error on `task1` triggers both error handlers. I only need to trigger `task1_error_handler`.
All the tasks are custom operators & the task ids ending with `status` are custom sensors.
How should I achieve this ?[image]

Comment: Can you post (parts) of your code instead of a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error on `task1` is causing both error handlers to occur because `task2` is downstream of `task1`, making `task1` a parent of task `task2`.

With your trigger rule being `ONE_FAILED` for both `task1` and `task2`, this is causing problems because the the definition of `ONE_FAILED` is:

> fires as soon as at least one parent has failed, it does not wait for all parents to be done

So with that said, you only want the `task1_error_handler` to trigger if `task1` fails. This cannot be easily done by just changing the trigger rule unfortunately because you can't directly link a conditional task like you want to currently.

Your best bets would be:

- Keep task1 as it is and to get rid of `task2`'s error handler trigger rule and instead use `on_failure_callback` to call the error handler.
- Split task2 into a separate DAG.

Comment: Thanks Zack. Individual error handlers are advised to go via error call backs instead of trigger rule ?  To avoid another DAG I thought of having a ShortCircut / PythonBranchOperator to skip after checking immediate parent task id. Is there a way to get that from context ?

Comment: @BillGoldberg Hey Bill - it depends on the DAG. I truly don't believe there is a standard for error handling in Airflow yet, but we use on_failure_callback for individual tasks in a DAG and trigger rules if we want to evaluate the whole DAG. I have no experience in using the PythonBranchOperator in the way you're describing either unfortunately, but maybe using an xcom_pull() would get you what you need!

Answer (score 1):

You can catch error in task1 code, skip all branches but error handlers and reraise error. For example, if task1 is `BashOperator`, replace it with the following `CatchBashOperator`:

```py
class CatchMixin(SkipMixin):

    def execute(self, context: Dict):
        try:
            super().execute(context)
        except Exception as e:
            ti = context['ti']
            task = ti.task
            excl_rules = [TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED, TriggerRule.ALL_FAILED]
            excl_tasks_ids = [t.task_id for t in task.downstream_list if t.trigger_rule in excl_rules]
            self.skip_all_except(ti, excl_tasks_ids)
            raise e


class CatchBashOperator(CatchMixin, BashOperator):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: The propesed solution might be wrong but you would still get the idea that I'm trying to achieve what [Logic Gates do in Digital Circuits](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/CAL/digital-logic/gatesfunc/) which might help you come up with a working solution. I encourage you to provide feedback*

---

[@Zack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55069972/3679900) pin-points the problem very well. I'd just like to add a workaround I have in mind.

If we create some new **dummy tasks and dependencies** as follows, it might just do the trick.

1. A `DummyOperator` with `trigger_rule=ONE_FAILED` in place of `task2_error_handler`. Its success means that `task2` has failed (which could very well be because of failure of `task1`)

   > ```
   > from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
   > from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
   > ..
   > task2_dummy_error_handler = DummyOperator(
   >                               dag=my_dag,
   >                               task_id="task2_dummy_error_handler",
   >                               trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED
   >                             )
   > [task2, task2_status_check] >> task2_dummy_error_handler
   > ```
2. Another `DummyOperator` with `trigger_rule=ALL_SUCCESS` that informs whether `task1` had *succeeded or not*. Its failure would mean that `task1` had failed => `task2` would automatically fail because of `UPSTREAM_FAILED` hence we need not run `task2_retry_handler`

   > ```
   > task1_error_handler_status_check = DummyOperator(
   >                                      dag=my_dag,
   >                                      task_id="task1_error_handler_status_check",
   >                                      trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS
   >                                    )
   > [task1, task1_status_check] >> task1_error_handler_status_check
   > ```
3. Finally set `trigger_rule=ALL_SUCCESS` in your `task2_retry_handler` and make it *downstream* of above two dummy tasks. This *should* ensure that `task2_retry_handler` runs on failure of `task2` but not on failure of `task1`.

   > ```
   > task2_retry_handler = PythonOperator(
   >                         dag=my_dag,
   >                         task_id="task2_retry_handler",
   >                         python_callable=my_task2_retry_handler,
   >                         ..,
   >                         trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS
   >                       )
   > [task1_error_handler_status_check, task2_dummy_error_handler] >> task2_retry_handler
   > ```

---

References

- [State](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/utils/state.py), [TriggerRule](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/utils/trigger_rule.py), [TriggerRuleDep](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/ti_deps/deps/trigger_rule_dep.py)
- [@Zack's answer on "Run Task on Success or Fail but not on Skipped"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794830/3679900)